# Find $a$ inverse modulo 30, $1\le a \le 30$. For each $a$ you find, find the inverse of each $a$ that have inverse modulo 30

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Find $a$ inverse modulo 30, $1\le a \le 30$. For each a you find, find the inverse of each a that have inverse modulo 30

a={1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}

They got a by the fact that relative primes are inverses. I was wondering if this rule also applied if $a \ge 30$?

**Find the inverse of each of the integers in a that have an inverse modulo 30**

Not really sure how to do this part

Comment: "*which is essentially all primes*"  Look at this again.  $3$ is not relatively prime to $30$.  Neither is $5$.  On the other hand, $7$ is relatively prime to $30$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, but note that $7\times13\equiv1\pmod{30}$.

Comment: This is not clear. $13\times 7 \equiv 1 \pmod {30}$ since $13\times 7=91\equiv 1 \pmod {30}$.  Thus the inverse of $7\pmod {30}$ is $13$.

Comment: As for how to find the inverses... one suggested search term you can use is "Extended Euclidean Division Algorithm"

Comment: "*I was under the impression that relative prime mean $ax\equiv 1\pmod{30}$*"  Relatively prime is usually defined as meaning $a$ is relatively prime to $b$ iff $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  You can find other equivalent conditions to this of course, but that is the one you should be leaning towards first.

Comment: How does extended Euclidean division algorithm help?